# cypher aggregating common node type between two distinct node types

Tags: neo4j, redis, cypher, graph-databases, redisgraph

[image: Graph View]

- I have two distinct types of nodes (LABELS in redisgraph). The blue circles in the diagram are called `WORKLOAD`. The yellow ones are called `API`.
- Between two workloads, there is a relationship/edge `ACCESSES_WORKLOAD` (indicated by the lightest blue/cyan edge). In the attached image, `front-end` workload accesses `user` and `order` workloads. The `order` workload accesses `user` workload.
- Between a `API` node and a `WORKLOAD` node there exists two types of relationships/edges. One is called a `CONTAINS_API` (dark blue link in the image) and another is called a `ACCESSES_API` (violet link in the image). For example, in the attached image, the `user` workload contains eight `API`s, Out of which six are consumed by `front-end` (the list: includes `3 /customers/...`, `/addresses`, `/register`, `/cards`). The two remaining `API`s are consumed by the `orders` (the list: `/cards/{cardsId}` and `/addresses/{addressesId}`.
- The `front-end` also accesses three `API` that are contained by the `orders` workload too (`/orders/...`)
- It is also possible that two `WORKLOAD`s may have an `ACCESSES_WORKLOAD` edge between them, but without any `API` as node as common between them.
- A `WORKLOAD` may have an extra edge/relationship called `CAUSES_ATTACK` to an `API` in addition to the `ACCESSES_API` edge. It is indicated by green color in the image. This may not exist always. In the attached image, the `front-end` workload has this edge to the `/catalogue/sock` API but not with any of the other `API`s.

Now I want to get the list of all workload-pairs and the ID of the `API` nodes in between them, if any. The cypher query that I tried is:

```
MATCH (w1)
MATCH (w1)-[awe:ACCESSES_WORKLOAD]->(w2 {deleted_time: -1})
OPTIONAL MATCH (w2)-[:CONTAINS_API]->(a:API)
OPTIONAL MATCH (w1)-[:ACCESSES_API]->(a)
OPTIONAL MATCH (w1)-[cae:CAUSES_ATTACK]->(a)
WHERE ID(w1) IN %s
RETURN DISTINCT awe, w1, w2, collect(ID(a)), collect(distinct cae.name)
```

An output that I was expecting was table like below:

```
w1             | w2          | API IDs List           | Attack Name
======================================================================
front-end-node | user-node   | [6 elements in a list] | null
orders-node    | user-node   | [2 elements in a list] | null
front-end-node | orders-node | [3 elements in a list] | null
front-end-node | some-node   | [1 element in a list]  | attack-name
```

But what I am getting is:

```
w1             | w2          | API IDs List           | Attack Name
======================================================================
front-end-node | user-node   | [8 elements in a list] | null
orders-node    | user-node   | [8 elements in a list] | null
front-end-node | orders-node | [3 elements in a list] | null
front-end-node | some-node   | [1 element in a list]  | attack-name
```

In the first two rows, for the `user` node, I am getting the list of all the `API`s contained by the `user` workload and not just the `API`s accessed by the `front-end` and `orders`. The `collect(ID(a))` is aggregating all the `API` nodes with a `CONTAINS_API` edge/relationship with the `w2 WORKLOAD` in the query instead of the `API`s with only `ACCESSES_API` with `w1 workload`.

If I were to map my expectation to JSON for brevity, the output I require will be like:

```
{
  sourceWorkloadID: <ID(front-end)>
  targetWorkloadID: <ID(user)>
  apis: [ ID(/cards), ID(/register), ID(/addresses), ID(/customers/...)]  // len here is six
  attack: null
},
{
  sourceWorkloadID: <ID(orders)>
  targetWorkloadID: <ID(user)>
  apis: [ ID(/cards/{cardsId), ID(/addresses/{addressesId})] // len here is two
  attack: null
}, {3rd row}, {4th row}
```

Can someone help fix the cypher query ? I am doing this in `redisgraph` via `cypher`. I cannot use neo4j-only query options/utils/helpers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to do the edge matching into the same line as the API MATCH:

```
MATCH (w1)
MATCH (w1)-[awe:ACCESSES_WORKLOAD]->(w2 {deleted_time: -1})
OPTIONAL MATCH (w2)-[:CONTAINS_API]->(a:API)<-[:ACCESSES_API]-(w1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (w1)-[cae:CAUSES_ATTACK]->(a)
WHERE ID(w1) IN %s
RETURN DISTINCT awe, w1, w2, collect(ID(a)), collect(distinct cae.name)
```